# The class of a table (created with createElement) doesn't work correctly in this code

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have created a table with document.createElement('table') and a class with table.className, but when I run the code some properties (like border-color and border-collapse) don't work. I don't know why this happens.

I'm trying to figure out wether this comes from the properties, the atributte className, o something else. I really don't have a clue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Ejemplo aprenderaprogramar.com</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            margin-top: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            color: mediumturquoise;
        }

        #div1 {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: solid 1px gray;
            border-radius: 7px;
            margin: 100px auto;
        }

        .tabla{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            border-style: solid  ;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-color:black ;
            font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;

        }


    </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {


            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            body.appendChild(table);
            table.className="tabla";

         }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Calendar</h1>

    <div id="div1">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your CSS code for .tabla, **border-collapse** and **border-color** cancels each other out. Maybe that's why it doesn't seem to show on the webpage.

```
.tabla {
    border-color:black ;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know they cancel each other. Thanks.